# Ubuntu doesn't see a probably damaged SD card

Tags: mount, 17.04, gparted, sd-card, testdisk

I have a damaged sd card, so i would like to format it. First i tried with Windows. Windows see my sd card, but when i try to format it, i get error. After i tried with the chkdsk command, but i get an error: `The type of the filesystem is RAW. CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.` So i tried Easeus Partition Master but i can't format it anyway. Now i want to try with Ubuntu. But Ubuntu unlike Windows don't see sd. I tried to use Gparted and Testdisk, but i can't see it anyway. I also read some topic about this problem, but none help me.

Edit: i did `dmesg` and i get an long output and at the end of the output i get

```
[   68.811545] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[   68.894696] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[   68.974302] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[   69.054154] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
```

Edit 2: i tried `sudo lsblk -f` , `sudo lsblk -m` ,

`sudo lsblk -o model,name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint` and `sudo parted -ls` but i can't see it anyway

P.S. sorry my bad english

Comment: After inserting the sd-card, try to run `dmesg` in a terminal. The last lines should give information about the sd-card, if Ubuntu sees it at all. Please update your question with this info.

Comment: Do other SD cards work in your reader ?

Comment: Yes, they work.

Comment: A damaged sdcard should be replaced, not formatted. There is no magic here.

Comment: If the partition table or file system is damaged, it can be repaired. But the card's hardware and built-in software can also be damaged, and there are no tools available for regular users (like you and me) to repair such damages. See the following link (and the list of actions, that you can try), https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Comment: @sudodus thanks for the reply. I tried to follow the third step, but i can't see the sd anyway.  I edited the question with the command that i tried

Comment: @mikewhatever before throw it away i want to be sure that i can't fix it.  Considering that Windows can see the sd but can't format, i want to try with Ubuntu before throw it away.

Comment: Did you try after reboot, in another computer, with another operating system, with another card reader (a USB card reader), after unplugging other USB devices? If you still cannot see the card as a mass storage device (with `lsblk`), I am afraid that the card is damaged beyond repair.

Comment: Have you tried inserting the SD card in a digicam and format it there? Sometimes digicams are very brutal and have some kind of built-in sledge hammer. I once experienced that. Just an idea.

Comment: @PerlDuck Thanks for the reply, i tried with a digicam but i get error memory card and can't format it.

Comment: @secon25 Yes, I was just grasping at straws. It was worth a try, though. Probably you should really throw it away and get a new one. As time goes by, they usually become cheaper, larger and faster anyway.

Comment: @sudodus I try with Windows but if i try to format i get error.  The last chance is the usb card reader. I'll try with a usb card reader in the next days, and if it will not work i will throw it away.                                                                 Thank you all for the answers.

Comment: @secon25, Good luck :-)